# How large was the visible universe at the time of the CMB?

Tags: cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background

Given that our best models so far suggest that the universe has been expanding *a lot* ever since the time the CMB was emitted, I'm wondering:

How large was the (visible) universe back at the time it became opaque and emitted the CMB?

Specifically, I'm curious as to the ("original") circumference of the spherical shell we "see" out there, in comparison to how far the light from it has traveled to reach us.

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/621281/123208

Comment: do you have any ideas based on the redshift?